# Is there any event for shapes?

Tags: c, winapi, tdm-gcc

I have an ***ellipse*** which is drew on a window. I want to show a message ***when the pointer is on it (on the ellipse)***. How I do it? Is there any event for shapes? Like `WM_MOVE` or `WM_SIZE`.

I use `TDM-GCC` and `C` language.

Comment: Win32 painting and input is done at the window level. it is the program's responsibility to understand what is happening inside its window. You might want to consider frameworks that provide higher-level functionality like an object model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no events for mouse activity over drawings.  You are expected to remember where you draw, and then map the mouse coordinates to the drawing coordinates yourself.  To help with this, have a look at the [`PtInRegion()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-ptinregion) function.  Create an elliptical `HRGN` via [`CreateEllipticRgn()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createellipticrgn) or [`CreateEllipticRgnIndirect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createellipticrgnindirect) that matches your drawing (in fact, you can use the same `HRGN` to help facilitate the drawing, see the [`FillRgn()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-fillrgn) function), and when you want to test if the mouse is currently inside the drawing, such as in a [`WM_MOUSEMOVE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-mousemove) handler, you can use `PtInRegion()` for that.

Comment: There's one more issue that needs to be addressed: Getting a notification when the mouse leaves the window altogether. [TrackMouseEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-trackmouseevent) allows you to do that. [Why is there no WM_MOUSEENTER message?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031013-00/?p=42193) offers helpful advice for an implementation.

Comment: @IInspectable I don't see what that has to do with this issue, but ok.

Comment: *"I want to show a message when the pointer is on it (on the ellipse)"*. Does that not imply, that you want whatever message is there to disappear, once your mouse pointer leaves the shape?

Comment: Leaving the *shape* inside the window, and leaving the *window* itself, are two different things.

Comment: Sometimes they are, and sometimes [they coincide](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031001-00/?p=42343). My comment was meant to address the situation, where they coincide.

Answer (score 3):

When you draw on a device context, all knowledge of what shape you draw is lost, and the system just retains the pixel by pixel information of that device context. So there is no way for the system to give you any information about the shapes that you draw because it knows nothing of those shapes.

In order to do what you want you need to keep track in your program of the high level logic of where your shapes are. Then when you handle mouse messages you can map them onto your own data structures that represent the shapes.

Comment: If all the knowledge of shapes will be lost, so how we can resize them after showing? Does system redraw them for resizing?

Comment: @RomanP No, *your program* redraws them for resizing. If it doesn't, then they might disappear when you resize the window.

Comment: You are expected to re-draw your shapes whenever the window needs to be re-drawn. Such as by doing the drawing inside of a `WM_PAINT` handler. When a window is resized, it can also be re-painted.